# Изменения формы SVG path по нажатию на checkbox?

Tags: css3, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Есть ли способ изменять узловые точки пути `path` для SVG изображений по нажатию на `checkbox`?

Приведу простой пример:

```css
 .st0 {
   fill: #FFFFFF;
   stroke: #000000;
   stroke-miterlimit: 10;
 }
```

```html
<label class="bl_label">
  <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <svg version="1.1" id="shape1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st0" d="M8.3,58.8c0,0,43.4-50,86.7,0z" />
  </svg>
</label>
```

Как по клику на `label` превращать данный путь (ну или другую дугу), скажем, в круг?
Есть ли метод без подключение JS библиотек по типу GSAP?

Comment: Добавил [второй ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1053410/28748) или уже неактуально?

Answer (score 2):

Работает, как тригер на одном чекбоксе.

В начальном состоянии дуга видна (path) - `stroke="grey"`
Круг  спрятан (circle) - `stroke="none"`

при отметке чекбокса  строка патча прячетчся

```
.input_checkbox:checked ~ svg path {
  stroke: none;
}
```

одновременно при отметке чекбокса строка круга показывается.

```
 .input_checkbox:checked ~ svg circle {
      stroke: grey;
    }
```

**Ниже полный код**

```css
 .input_checkbox:checked ~ svg path {
  stroke: none;
} 

.input_checkbox:checked ~ svg circle {
  stroke: grey;
} 

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
   
<label for="input_checkbox">Hide stroke</label>
  <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <svg version="1.1" id="shape1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    <path class="st0" d="M8.3,58.8c0,0,43.4-50,86.7,0z" stroke-width="1" stroke="grey" fill="none" /> 
 <circle class="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="none" fill="none">
  </svg>
```

Comment: Немного не тот эффект. Необходим именно переход (анимация) из одного path в другой. Допустим что количество точек путей у нас одинаковое и нам необходимо поменять их координаты. Что-то на подобии MorphSVG

Comment: Да, более, чем. Буду очень признателен. Мне интересно как это в принципе возможно, с подвязкой на checkbox ?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь надо использовать [псевдокласс](http://htmlbook.ru/css/checked) `checked` и `element + element` [селектор](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp).

Берем два элемента в `svg` и один прячем. А там уже по селектором когда нажали на `checkbox` видимость меняется местами. Все с помощью `css`.

```css
 .st0 {
   fill: #FFFFFF;
   stroke: #000000;
   stroke-miterlimit: 10;
 }
 .st1{
   display: none;
 }
 
.input_checkbox:checked + svg>.st0{
  display: none;
}
.input_checkbox:checked + svg>.st1{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="bl_label">
  <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <svg version="1.1" id="shape1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st0" d="M8.3,58.8c0,0,43.4-50,86.7,0z" />
    <circle class="st1" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  </svg>
</label>
```

Comment: Немного не то. Тут два пути, один скрывается второй показывается, по сути в место круга может быть вообще всё что угодно. Нужна плавность перехода

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Ответ поменяю, но про плавность в вопросе нечего не сказано, для этого нормально сформулируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

### Плавный морфинг фигур

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
}

input:checked~svg .hide {
  display:block;
}
input:checked~svg .show {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" >
  <svg class="curtain home" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
            <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" fill="url(#img1)" class="show">
        </polygon>
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" fill="url(#img1)" class="hide">
            <animate attributeName="points" dur="5s" values="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0 ; 50,40 30,60 80,10 50,70; 0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </polygon>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Или используйте событие click. Хитрость заключается в том, чтобы иметь два прямоугольника, один для начала и другой для конца. С помощью некоторых CSS правил вы делаете их друг над другом и играете с `z-index`:

Вот базовый пример, вам просто нужно найти хороший способ, чтобы красный прямоугольник выглядел лучше, так как это будет только тот, который вы должны нажимать.

```css
label {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}

input:checked + label {
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="input" >
  <label for="input"><svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" height="20">
        <rect id="stop" x=0 y=0 width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
  </svg></label>
  <label for="input"><svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" height="20">
        <rect id="start" x=0 y=0 width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
  </svg></label>

  <svg class="curtain home" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
            <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" fill="url(#img1)" class="hide">
            <animate attributeName="points" begin="start.click" end="stop.click"  dur="5s" values="0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0 ; 50,40 30,60 80,10 50,70; 0,0 0,100 100,100 50,0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </polygon>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Если вы заинтересованы в CSS-решении, это может быть легко сделано с помощью нескольких строк кода:

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  display:block;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 50% 0);
  animation:change 5s linear infinite paused;
}
input:checked + img {
  animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes change{
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(50% 40%, 30% 60%, 80% 10%, 50% 70%)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" >
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/800/800">
```